# sql concat partial fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have this trigger:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER insert_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON staff
FOR EACH ROW
SET new.staffUsername = CONCAT(new.staffFirstName, new.staffLastName)
```

which creates the following results:

staffFirstName - dave

staffLastName - smith

staffUsername - davesmith

however I would like the result to be dsmith, so it takes only the first letter of staffFirstName and joins it with staffLastName. How can I edit my trigger to do this automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a left  for the staffFirstName

```
SET new.staffUsername = CONCAT(left(new.staffFirstName,1), new.staffLastName)
```

Comment: I intended to but couldn't at the time since there is a timer on it.